# Плохо понимаю смысл этих строк в языке Си

Tags: c, указатели, struct, typedef

Столкнулся с проблемой, что имею плохое представление о смысле этих строк.

```
typedef struct tdate {
int year, day, month;
} TDate;

typedef struct tperson{
char *name;
TDatum birthday;
} TPerson;
```

1. Почему это используется?
2. Как обращаться к элементам этой структуры?
3. Плохо понимаю что даёт запись в конце каждой из них `} TDate;` и `} TPerson;`
4. Не понимаю какие особенности у указателя на структуру

Прошу максимально подробно объяснить каждый элемент этого кода, дабы восполнить этот пробел.

РS. 
Знаю понятие структуры.
Не очень хорошо, но всё таки понимаю понятие указатель

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом фрагменте совмещено определение типа и создание синонима типа. Чтобы было понятнее нужно разбить действия на несколько частей:

Определение структуры tdate:

```
struct tdate {
int year, day, month;
};
```

В этом определении создается тип "структура" с именем "tdate". В принципе с ним уже можно работать, можно создавать переменные типа "tdate" и обращаться к полям данных этих переменных. Например так:

```
int main(){

tdate aaa;

aaa.day=0;
aaa.day++;

return 0;
}
```

Однако дальше автор не останавливается на достигнутом и, кроме создания типа "tdate", хочет создать еще и синоним для типа "tdate". Это делается с помощью декларации typedef:

```
typedef tdate TDate;
```

Теперь можно создавать переменные типа "tdate" и переменные типа "TDate". Причем 
переменные типа "TDate" будут иметь те же поля что и переменные типа "tdate". Пример:

```
int main(){

tdate aaa;
TDate bbb;

aaa.day=0;
bbb.day=1;

return 0;
}
```

В этом примере создаются две переменные. Одна переменная типа "tdate" с именем "aaa" и другая переменная типа "TDate" с именем "bbb". Поля обоих переменных одинаковы. Доступ к полям возможен через точку после имени переменной, как показано в примере.

В общем случае надо различать:

1. Имена встроенных в язык типов таких как int, float и прочих.
2. Имена пользовательских типов (объявляются с помощью ключевого слова struct).
3. Имена синонимов типов (объявляются с помощью ключевого слова typedef).
4. Имена переменных вновь созданных типов. В примере это "aaa" и "bbb".
5. Имена полей структуры. В примере это "day".

Вот весь код, который можно компилировать:

```
struct tdate {
int year, day, month;
};

typedef tdate TDate;

int main(){

tdate aaa;//создание переменной типа "tdate" с именем "aaa"
TDate bbb;//создание переменной типа "TDate" с именем "bbb"

aaa.day=0;//работа с полем "day" переменной "aaa"
bbb.day=1;//работа с полем "day" переменной "bbb"

return 0;
}
```

Чтобы было еще понятнее вот создание переменной типа int и с именем "aaa" и работа с ней:

```
int main(){

int aaa;

aaa=0;

return 0;
}
```

PS. Эх, где мои семнадцать лет... :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. typedef хорошая штука. Она создает псевдоним типа. Создавать экземпляр объявленной структуры, благодаря typedef, можно несколькими способами:

   ```
   struct tdate tmp1;`
   TDate tmp2;
   ```

   согласитесь, второй удобнее.
2. К элементам структуры обращаются через точку

   ```
   tmp2.year = 2017;
   ```

   Если структура задана через указатель, то вместо точки используется ->

   ```
   TDate* pTmp3;
   pTmp3->year = 2017;
   ```
3. Ответил в первом пункте.
4. Указатель на структуру позволяет передавать конкретную структуру в функцию, не копируя её (структуры) содержимого. При этом внутри функции обращаться к элементам структуры нужно через ->, и изменение элементов структуры внутри функции будет менять именно ту структуру, указатель которой передали в функцию.

Comment: То есть если в конце структуры с typedef не написать ...} TDate; , то к её элементам нельзя будет обратиться?

Comment: @RomanYaremchuk до обращения и дело-то не дойдёт, всё кончится ошибкой компиляции на объявлении `TDate tmp2;`, т. к. типа `TDate` не будет существовать.